# How do I get the area of a WGS84 polygon in square meters?

Tags: postgis, area, wgs84

The following gives me the area of the polygon in square degrees:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((871325.790874952 6105405.3261047,871418.748307692 6105359.72944624,871346.22022442 6105215.141258,871254.85408906 6105261.72007212,871325.790874952 6105405.3261047))',4326)) As sqm;
```

Result: 16586.2319335938

How do I get the area in square meters? I tried the following:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((871325.790874952 6105405.3261047,871418.748307692 6105359.72944624,871346.22022442 6105215.141258,871254.85408906 6105261.72007212,871325.790874952 6105405.3261047))',4326)),31467) As sqm;
```

But it seems like ST_Transform doesn't work. I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  function st_transform(geometry) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((871325...
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********
 ERROR: function st_transform(geometry) does not exist
SQL Status:42883
Hint:No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Missing Proj support shouldn't be the problem, with SELECT PostGIS_full_version() I get

```
"POSTGIS="1.5.3" GEOS="3.3.3-CAPI-1.7.4" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" LIBXML="2.8.0" USE_STATS"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a closing paren in the wrong place towards the end of your query.  I tried this and got a NaN return,

```
SELECT ST_AREA(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((871325.790874952 6105405.3261047,871418.748307692 6105359.72944624,871346.22022442 6105215.141258,871254.85408906 6105261.72007212,871325.790874952 6105405.3261047))',4326),31467)) As sqm;
```

The NaN result is due to the polygon being outside the limits of your projection.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Apart from that the projections have to be 900913 and 31467: `SELECT ST_AREA(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((871325.790874952 6105405.3261047,871418.748307692 6105359.72944624,871346.22022442 6105215.141258,871254.85408906 6105261.72007212,871325.790874952 6105405.3261047))',900913),31467)) As sqm;`

Answer (score 3):

```
ST_Transform(geometry,target_CRS)
```

is the correct syntax. You seem to have mixed up some commas.

Answer (score 3):

Both queries define the SRID for the polygon as 4326, but based on the data this is surely not the case. SRID 4326 (WGS84) is limited to the range [-90,90] for latitude and [-180,180] for longitude.

If you have polygon data in 4326, then using the [ST_GeogFromText](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_GeogFromText.html) may be a better approach. This assumes that your data are in 4326, and measurements on geography features will be in meters.

A working query follows:

```
SELECT
ST_Area(
ST_Transform(
ST_SetSRID(
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON((-98.4854749658124 29.3495134003054,-97.4374094977531 29.4150174920591,-97.2408972224919 28.4979602075071,-98.354466782305 28.4324561157534,-98.4854749658124 29.3495134003054))'
)
, 4326)
, 900913)
)
```

I transformed to 900913 instead of 31467 because that SRID doesn't cover my example data's area.